# html parsing using htmlcleaner

Tags: html-parsing, htmlcleaner

i want to parse this type of html using html cleaner..

```
<div class="result-item yt-uix-tile yt-tile-default *sr">
    <div class="thumb-container">
      <a href="/watch?v=NZiEqhrIL_k" class="ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto result-item-thumb">
        <span class="video-thumb ux-thumb yt-thumb-default-138 ">
            <span class="yt-thumb-clip">
                <span class="yt-thumb-clip-inner">
                  <img onload="tn_load(2)" alt="Thumbnail" src="//i3.ytimg.com/vi/NZiEqhrIL_k/default.jpg" width="138" >
                  <span class="vertical-align"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
  <span class="video-time">2:40</span>
```

in it i only want to get href ( href="/watch?v=NZiEqhrIL_k"  ) value. how can i achieve it. thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing at least 2 `</divs>` and a `</a>` but for the life of me I can't reason what you're intending

Comment: i want to get links of videos from youtube in my app?

Comment: now it is more specific i want to get href from this <a href="/watch?v=6_NpdRUomaY" class="yt-uix-tile-link" dir="ltr" title="Pee Jaun - Farhan Saeed Butt ft.Momina Mustehsan [ OFFICIAL MUSIC VIDEO ] HD" >Pee Jaun - Farhan Saeed Butt ft.Momina Mustehsan [ OFFICIAL MUSIC VIDEO ] HD</a></h3>

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty, in javascript,

so for each line in your return, set thisLine:

```
var thisLine = "<a href=\"/watch?v=NZiEqhrIL_k\" class=\"ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto result-item-thumb\">";
```

then find the start of the bit you want and the end:

```
var startPos = thisLine.indexOf("<a href=\"/watch?");  
    thisLine = thisLine.substring(startPos+2);
var endPos = thisLine.indexOf("class=");
    thisLine = thisLine.substring(0,endPos-1);
```

There's probably a 1000 ways to do this...  look at the **Related** questions on the right side, or do a search for `parse html response`.